# GMF/Graphiti Eclipse based HTML editor

Tags: html, html-editor, eclipse

I'm looking for an HTML editor based on Eclipse, and I need that it was supported by [GMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Modeling_Framework) or [Graphiti](https://eclipse.org/graphiti/). Anybody knows if there exists an editor with this characteristics?

It must allow me to model a web page, and this model conforms to a HTML metamodel.

I need that this model is based on EMF because I need to implement some transformations with [Xpand2](https://eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/?project=xpand) to generate finally HTML code.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: specific requirements. What features do you need?

Comment: Hello, I think the question is clear... Those who knows about Eclipse and GMF or Graphiti should know about what I'm asking for. If not, maybe this person could not answer this question.

Comment: I had edited it. But the question is so specific I think... Thank you so much!

Comment: Your only requirements listed are compatibility (I've integrated links for those not familiar with the terms, you might wish to cross-check them if I picked the right ones), features are lacking. Think e.g. of code folding, syntax highlighting, auto-completion, etc. Do you need any of those – or would Windows Notepad be sufficient if it were compatible here?